# ruby rvm rails generate scaffold fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake, rvm, scaffold

I have this following Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.1'

group :assets do
    gem 'sass-rails', '~> 3.2.3'
    gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
    gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Running rvm version:

```
$ rvm --version

rvm 1.10.2 by Wayne E. Seguin <wayneeseguin@gmail.com>, Michal Papis <mpapis@gmail.com> [https://rvm.beginrescueend.com/]
```

The generate scaffold fails with:

```
$ rvm all do rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
(in /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rails-0.9.5)
WARNING: 'require 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated.  Please use 'require 'rdoc/task' (in RDoc 2.4.2+)' instead.
at /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rake-0.9.2.2/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb
rake/gempackagetask is deprecated.  Use rubygems/package_task instead

rm -rf /tmp/demo_app/generate
rake aborted!
can't convert nil into String

Tasks: TOP => fresh_gem_rails => make_dir_structure => make_base_dirs
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
```

(One thing to mention that there is no Rakefile in the directory).

What does `can't convert nil into String` mean? (I tried to place `--trace` into various places onto the command line, but the messages didn't seem to change ...)

Also how do I correct the `RDoc` warning?

Thanks

Comment: I found an explanation for the `RDoc` warning at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702504/rails-how-do-i-resolve-the-rake-rdoctask-is-deprecated-warning
although it is unclear how to clear it up except by commenting lines in the Ruby source code ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That `rails-0.9.5` in `/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rails-0.9.5` sounds suspicious to me.

Are you sure your Rails installation isn't screwed up?

EDIT

And what's that `rvm all` for, anyway? I'm not an rvm guru, but from what I could gather it looks like it does something for all installed rubies, which most certainly isn't what you want here.

Comment: OK, I removed the directory
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rails-0.9.5
Now I see:

`$ rvm all do rails generate scaffold User name:string email:string
/home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/rails:19:in `load': cannot load such file -- /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/gems/rails-0.9.5/bin/rails (LoadError)
 from /home/user/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0/bin/rails:19:in `<main>'`
Somehow rails thinks to be at 0.9.5 ...

Comment: @gliptak: no no no, it's that `rvm all` that doesn't sound right, read my edit. Why are you using it? Why aren't you just using `rails generate ...`?

Comment: There seems to be no rails in /home/user/.rvm/bin (although there is bundle and rake executables). I'm reinstalling rvm.

Comment: I second @s.m.'s comment. You don't need to execute `rvm do`, and there shouldn't be a `rails` executable in `~/.rvm/bin`. You just need to execute `rvm use` before you run the Rails generator and all your Ruby/Rails commands will use the correct Ruby (and gemset if you specify one).

Comment: Reinstalled rvm. I might have missed (re)running
$ rvm alias create default ruby-1.9.3-p125