# OpenVZ web panel cron gives ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, rake-task, rdoc, openvz

I'm using OpenVZ on CentOS 6.5 64bit and every morning I'm getting message with following content:

> /etc/cron.daily/owp.cron:
>
> /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.1/lib/rake/rdoctask.rb:2: ERROR: 'rake/rdoctask' is obsolete and no longer supported. Use 'rdoc/task' (available in RDoc 2.4.2+) instead. (RuntimeError)
>
> ```
> from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
> from /usr/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
> from /opt/ovz-web-panel//script/cron_runner:11
> ```

Can anybody advise what to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rails: how do I resolve the 'rake/rdoctask'' is deprecated' warning?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702504/rails-how-do-i-resolve-the-rake-rdoctask-is-deprecated-warning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I have fixed this issue by running following in SSH:

## gem install rdoc-rake

No more warning.

Answer (score -1):

`rake/rdoctask` is obsolete. Change it to `rdoc/task` in your `Rakefile`.

Check this [issue](https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/issues/157) for more details.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer. But as I don't have good knowledge in this language , I'd much appreciate if you please provide where should I change things? Thanks a lot again.

Comment: locate `Rakefile` in your project and update that file

Comment: Thanks, but there's no such string "rake/rdoctask" to change at /usr/lib64/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-10.1.1/Rakefile

any advise?

Comment: Can anybody help me with this? Much appreciate! Thanks!